# Sign in with Ethereum through a CLI

Tags: ethereumjs, authentication

I have a ts-node backend and I would like to use [Sign In With Ethereum] (https://login.xyz/) to connect user's wallet through a CLI. The user passes his private key as a parameter.

Comment: Please add more details.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of asking user to pass their private key, which is very insecure and against the whole idea of blockchain technology, you should

- Print out a message users need to sign
- Ask users to sign this message in their wallet
- Then copy-paste the resulting message to the console

This way private key is never exposed and wallets work as intended.

If this workflow is too cumbersome for your user, alternative you can just make a

- Static HTML website
- When entered to the page it asks user to sign a message
- The webpage outputs the result
- The webpage copies the result to the clipboard
- The user can paste the copied result to the console to complete the sign in